# Deny GetObject for all S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to create an IAM role with a read-only policy (arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess).

In order to prevent access to all objects on all buckets, I added a Deny section in Cloudformation template:

```yaml
  ReadOnlyAccessRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: /
      RoleName: read-only-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Ref AwsAccount
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      
          - Effect: Deny
            Sid: DenyS3GetObject
            Action: s3:GetObject
            Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::/*"

      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
```

I get a "MalformedPolicyDocument" error in the Deny section (Resource).

I already tested these options :

- Resource: "*"
- Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::/*"
- Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::prefix-bucket*"

Do you have any idea about this syntax error ?

EDIT :

Error from Cloudformation :

> Blockquote Has prohibited field Resource (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: ......; Proxy: null)

Comment: This role will be used for a specific purpose, they asked Read-Only access to aws services without being able to access data. So they can list existing buckets for example or some stats (size)..

Comment: Please add the entire error message.

Comment: AssumeRolePolicyDocument should contain the trust policy (who is allowed to assume the role). The inline policy itself should be an independent YAML fragment under [Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-policies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `Policies` section.

Try something like this:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Resources:
  MyTestRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: read-only-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Ref AwsAccount
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: EmbeddedInlinePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Deny
                Action: s3:GetObject
                Resource: '*'
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess
```

Comment: Hi John, you beat me by a minute. I need a browser extension for Stack Overflow that detects your answers and tells me to stop working on a problem ;-)

Comment: @jarmod `if True: stop_working()`